# Is the function $f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\chi_{[n,n+1)}$ Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is the function $f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\chi_{[n,n+1)}$ Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$? Justify your answer.

I came across this question on a past exam paper for a measure theory course I'm taking and I can't find anything similar in my professors notes to help me work through it. I have a feeling that I should be using a convergence theorem but I'm not quite sure which one. A push in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n}$ converges.

Comment: @EDX $\chi_A$ is the function which is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ off of $A$.

Comment: @EDX: There is no loss of meaning in writing things like $f\cdot g$ and $cf$ where $f,g$ are functions and $c$ is a real number.

Comment: Yep sorry ahah   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f| &=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\chi_{[n,n+1)}  \right|\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}|\chi_{[n,n+1)}|\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[n,n+1)}&\because\text{Monotone Convergence Theorem}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-n}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=2\\&<\infty  
\end{align*}

Therefore, $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Here you can compute the value of the integral directly using monotone convergence:

$$\int|f|=\int\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum^N_{k=10}2^{-k}\mathbb{1}_{[k,k+1})=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\sum^n_{k=1}2^{-k}\mathbb{1}_{[k,k+1)}=\lim_n\sum^n_{k=0}2^{-k}=2<\infty$$

Comment: Lev thinks the sum of this geometric series is $2$, not $1/2$.